# faster way to write INNER JOIN function

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL:
I'm trying to add some data to my table from another table, where their id is the same.

```
update sf_leads t1
inner join temp_geninfo t2 
on t1.application_id = t2.application_id
set t1.org_city = t2.org_city;
```

However, each table has 92,000 values, and this query has been taking nearly an hour to finish. Is there a faster way to do this, or do I just need to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
update sf_leads t1 inner join
       temp_geninfo t2 
       on t1.application_id = t2.application_id
    set t1.org_city = t2.org_city;
```

You want an index on `temp_geninfo(application_id, org_city)`:

```
create index idx_temp_geninfo_application_id_org_city on temp_geninfo(application_id, org_city);
```

You also might want to check that you don't have multiple updates on the same row, by running:

```
select application_id, count(*)
from temp_geninfo
group by application_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

If this returns any rows, then you potentially have the problem of the `join` multiplying the number of rows being updated.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to indexes, do I just create the index and then run my original code?

Comment: @bguan2020 . . . Just create the index once.  Then I would recommend just running the `join` as a `select` query and counting the rows that are returned.  That should be pretty fast.

Comment: wow this is useful... went from almost an hour to 17 seconds. wish I learned about these earlier haha